# Electron Content Security Policy refusing to connect to Heroku API with a meta tag

Tags: heroku, electron, content-security-policy

I'm working with Electron for the first time, and while most of this app is configured okay, I'm running right into Content Security Policy problems.

The app itself is a game, and needs to connect to a multiplayer server - which has different endpoints. MOST of my CSP settings work by now, except for the connections to Heroku:

```html
    <meta
    http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
    content="
      default-src 'self' capacitor-electron://* 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' data: 'unsafe-inline' wss://*.herokuapp.com:443/*;
    "
    />
```

When I connect to the game, it's giving me this error:

```
Refused to connect to 'https://herokuapp.com/matchmake/create/' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self' capacitor-electron://* 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' data: 'unsafe-inline' wss://*.herokuapp.com:443/*". Note that 'connect-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.
```

The actual call related to it is performed by wss:// - not https://. Am I missing a CSP setting to cover this, or is this an Electron issue?

Answer (score 0):

Websockets start by connecting over HTTP(S), then [upgrade](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Protocol_upgrade_mechanism) to WS(S).

You'll need to include `https://herokuapp.com` in your sources as well as `wss`. You can see this what it's trying to connect to in the error message, if you look closely.

A few extra notes:

- You have `'unsafe-inline'` twice.
- `'unsafe-inline'` is the most important to *disable* for a CSP. (Maybe you're doing it incrementally, getting it working first, but definitely don't leave this in for an Electron app!)
- You may have to remove `/*` from the end of the `wss` one, I don't know if that's valid.
- You should put the game server allowances in `connect-src`, so that scripts can't be loaded from it.